# programatically search products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, advanced-search

programatically search products in magento 2. Please help me to get products using search criteria.

Comment: may i know whether you are looking for the  the code to implement the api ?

Comment: How to apply filters for the above search API, I'm getting the product collection properly but not able to apply filters and sort order using addAttributeToFilter function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to search Product programatically, try below code.

I used **SKU** to get Products.

Call this in your template file.

```
    #File: app/code/Pulsestorm/RepositoryTutorial/Command/Examples.php   

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    //create our filter
    $filter_1 = $objectManager
    ->create('Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder')
    ->setField('sku')
    ->setConditionType('like')
    ->setValue('WSH')    // you can also use wildcard here e.g. %WSH%
    ->create();

    //add our filter(s) to a group
    $filter_group = $objectManager
    ->create('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder')
    ->addFilter($filter_1)
    ->create();
    
    // $filter_group->setData('filters', [$filter]);

    //add the group(s) to the search criteria object
    $search_criteria = $objectManager
    ->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder')
    ->setFilterGroups([$filter_group])
    ->create();

    $productdata  = $objectManager
    ->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')
    ->getList($search_criteria)
    ->getItems();  
    
        foreach ($productdata as $product) {
            echo  $product->getSKU();
        }
```

Reference: [enter link description here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/)

Let me know If you have issue.

Comment: No issues,  the code is working fine....thank you..

Comment: @glad to hear that

Answer (score 4):

Please use the below code, might be useful for you. here i am giving u test script 
just copy and past in the test script and run the code as shown in the screenshots

EX: http://testsite.com/filename.php?q={yoursearchterm}

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$layerResolver = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$layerResolvers = $layerResolver->create('search');
$layerResolvers1 = $layerResolver->get();
$productCollection = $layerResolvers1->getProductCollection();

echo "Search layered navigation :<br>";
echo "products count == ".count($productCollection)."<br>";
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo "Name : ".$product->getName()." Price : ".$product->getPrice()."<br>";

}
?>
```

**Screenshots:** :

http://prntscr.com/g5a203

http://prntscr.com/g5a238

Comment: I am looking for custom search api

Comment: This does not return the products related to my search query.